# How can use expo icons in react native app created by create-react-native-app my-project

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I used `create-react-native-app my-project` but I want to use icons from `@expo/vector-icons`

### Code

```
import { Ionicons} from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function App(){

 return <Ionicons name={Platform.OS === 'ios'?"ios-happy-outline":"md-happy"} size={100}/>}
```

### Actual result

```
Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
```

### Expected result

Icons should be visible on my User interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **react-native-vector-icons** from https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/

- first Install the Dependency (react-native-vector-icons) by

  npm install react-native-vector-icons
- Create **assets/fonts** directory in **android/app/src/main**
- Once you create the fonts directory copy all the font files from **node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts** into it
- Now in App.js you can react-native-vector-icons like below

  ```
   import React from "react";
   import {Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
   import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

   // https://icons.expo.fyi   for icons



   export default function toDoItems({item, pressHandler}){

       return(
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> pressHandler(item.key)}>
               <View>
                   <Icon name="rocket" size={30} color="#900" />
                   <Text style={styles.item}>{item.text}</Text>
               </View>
           </TouchableOpacity>
       )
   }
   const styles= StyleSheet.create({
       item :  {
           padding : 30,
           borderColor : 'black',
           borderWidth : 1,
           borderStyle : 'dashed',
           marginVertical : 20,
       }
   })
  ```

Comment: Do you need to copy the fonts somewhere under `ios/` for the iOS runtime too?